# Передать фокус элементу jQuery

Tags: html, jquery

На странице есть блок `<div>`, который отображается при `hover` на другой элемент.
Необходимо после его отображения передать ему фокус, так чтобы при `mouseout` сработало событие.
Сейчас `mouseout` срабатывает сразу при попытке подвести курсор к отображенному элементу.

Answer (score 1):

По `mouseenter` добавляйте единственный `mouseout`, с помощью `one` - http://api.jquery.com/one/

```
var el = $('.element');
el.on('mouseenter', function() { el.one('mouseout', function () { ... }) });
```

`focus()` не влияет на положение курсора мыши

Answer (score 0):

[$('div_id').focus()](http://api.jquery.com/focus/)

Comment: сделал так - но mouseout не срабатывает